# Is there a tool to reliably solve or troubleshoot graphics and hybrid-graphics acceleration?

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, hybrid-graphics, tools

I consistently have issues with hybrid graphics on Ubuntu. From Ubuntu 12.04 up to 20.04, which is what I'm running at the moment. This might be a bit open ended but there is a lot of frustration behind it so any direction or suggestions would be greatly, immensely appreciated.

#### Pretext:

Windows detects and installs drivers and pretty much guarantees out of the box hardware accelerated video decode and 3D acceleration, in most hardware configs. Hybrid graphics works exactly the way it should.. Every time. Use Intel GPU out of the box, switch to discrete GPU for specific applications or for hardware decode/CUDA. The discrete GPU is always available in applications like Blender cycles even if not explicitly enabled for the application.

#### Knowns:

Xorg does not play well with graphics switching.
Wayland will be a dramatic improvement, but is wayy too buggy (screen sharing with chrome does not work, screen tearing etc).
Nobody buys a hybrid laptop and expects to never be able to use both GPU's.
Nobody wants to have no control over which GPU is in use.
There is no (As far as my many years of frustrating research goes) single solution.

#### Problems:

Ubuntu does not install nvidia drivers by default.
After installing nvidia drivers several problems arise:

- No hardware accelerated video decode in browsers (Chrome, Opera, Chromium)
- GPU is on All the Time. Using lots of battery.
- Blender still does not pick up nvidia GPU.
- Gnome and KDE both dip down to 15fps frequently with nothing but some VSCode instances open.
- After a suspend, Xorg goes to 10fps and pretty much dies until rebooted.

#### Half-baked solutions:

- Nvidia-prime -> Not automatic. Rebooting on a graphics switch is not viable. I haven't been able to get v-sync with Gnome or KDE running at all. Sometimes I get graphics dips down to 15fps with nothing but IDE's open. Haven't been able to get video decode working with this setup.

### Question:

Is there a distro/hardware combo that has none of these problems?
Would it be viable and/or desirable by the community to have a tool that can detect various common issues and fix/suggestAFix to get graphics acceleration working?
Would it be viable and/or desirable to have a website such as https://caniuse.com/ dedicated to showing what can/can't be done with specific distros/graphicStacks on specific hardware configurations?

Answer (score 1):

***Is there a distro/hardware combo that has none of these problems?***

No: If there were, everybody would be using it.

Hardware compatibility is handled by the Linux kernel. All Linux distros use the same kernel source. The problem is that a few hardware vendors don't provide kernel modules (drivers) for their hardware, or provide poor-quality (buggy) modules. There's little the kernel developers can do about that; the kernel developer rarely have access to the OEM source code for the hardware.

***Would it be viable and/or desirable by the community to have a tool that can detect various common issues and fix/suggestAFix to get graphics acceleration working?***

No: You're asking for an ongoing software development project that identifies common bugs and their fixes (if any). If you can fix a bug in the proposed application, that means you can also simply fix the original bug in the kernel module and skip all the overhead of an entire additional project. The hurdle is generally not telling users that they have a bug (the user already knows that their hardware does not work well) -- the hurdle is getting users to test the software and to report the bug in the first place and then to follow up and help developers test the bugfixes.

"*Windows detects and installs drivers*" because legions of OEM and Windows engineers are paid make X fit into Y. That doesn't mean the compatibility was easy; it just means that "somebody else" did that integration work for you already so it's easy *for you*. You're the customer -- you paid for all that Windows effort; it was baked into the price of your hardware.

But this is not Windows, and here the process is much more transparent -- you can see those developers (both paid and volunteer) hard at work, often asking for testing help from the community and getting limited response. Remember, you're not an Ubuntu or Linux *customer* -- there's no revenue from your use of Ubuntu.

***Would it be viable and/or desirable to have a website showing what can/can't be done with specific distros/graphicStacks on specific hardware configurations?***

Perhaps: Canonical does already employ a team of engineers in Taiwan who do hardware certification testing, and maintains a [searchable database of the result](https://certification.ubuntu.com/).

The problem with a website is that somebody must maintain it in an environment of constant change. Kernels update every couple weeks. Entire software stacks are replaced every six months. Older hardware must be tested with newer releases of software. Somebody must do all the testing. Somebody must investigate when two testers get differing results.

If somebody wants to create such a website, go right ahead. You don't need anybody's permission.